# Querying the USGS National Map from R

Tags: r, sf, watershed, usgs

I'm trying to download watershed boundary dataset geometries from the USGS National Map. Right now, I'm just trying to download 2 digit HU layers. You can see what I'm looking for [here](https://hydro.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/wbd/MapServer/1) and [here](https://water.usgs.gov/nawqa/sparrow/wrr97/geograp/reg_map.gif) is a low res image of what geometries I'm after (white outlines).

Here's the code I have so far:

```
library(httr)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# Base URL for the WBD service
base_url <- "https://hydro.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/wbd/MapServer/1/query?"

# Define query parameters
query_params <- list(
  where = "1=1",      # Query to select all features
  outFields = "*",    # Return all fields
  f = "json"          # Output format (e.g., geojson, json, etc.)
)

# Construct the full URL with query parameters
full_url <- modify_url(base_url, query = query_params)

# Make the GET request
response <- GET(full_url)

# Check for a successful response and parse the data
if (http_type(response) == "application/json") {
  # Parse the response
  data <- content(response, "parsed")
  # Process the data as needed
} else {
  cat("Unexpected response type:", http_type(response))
}
data
```

The query appears to work as I get a `200` response when I run `response$status`. But when I go to parse the data using the content function, I get a `500` response.

Anything I can do to make this work?

Comment: The 200 means the server returned ok, the 500 is the *service* saying you've got an error, in this case the JSON is `{"error":{"code":500,"message":"Error performing query operation","details":[]}}` - maybe you are asking for too much information? Can you do a more restrictive query rather than asking for all features and all fields? Does this work through a web browser?

Comment: Thank you @Spacedman! I spent some more time working through this and I think you are correct. It appears to be a size related issue because I can call for one HU at a time and it works. I'll update this with what worked for me shortly. If only 500 gave a little more info for the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a few more hours on this and I think it ended up being a size issue (thank you @Spacedman). Additionally, parsing the geoJSON was done best with the `geojsonsf` package as opposed to using the `httr` `content` function.

Here's the code that ended up working for me to download the 2 digit HU layers:

```
library(httr)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
library(leaflet)

# load the ids for all objects
id_url <- "https://hydro.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/wbd/MapServer/1/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPolygon&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&havingClause=&returnIdsOnly=true&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnExtentOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&quantizationParameters=&featureEncoding=esriDefault&f=json"

response <- GET(id_url)

# Check for a successful response and parse the data
if (http_type(response) == "application/json") {
    # Parse the response to text then use fromJSON to convert read json
    ids <- content(response, "text") %>%
        fromJSON() %>%
        as_tibble()
    # Process the data as needed
} else {
    cat("Unexpected response type:", http_type(response))
}

# define the base url for the layer queries
base_url <- "https://hydro.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/wbd/MapServer/1/query?"

# Define query parameters using map to iterate over the different object id's
# obtained via the query above
query_params <- purrr::map(ids$objectIds, ~ list(
    # objectIds filters to one HU at a time from the map call
    objectIds = .,      
    # return polygons
    geometryType = "esriGeometryPolygon",
    # return geometries
    returnGeometry = "true",
    # Output format (e.g., geojson, json, etc.)
    f = "geojson" 
))

# create list of full urls to map over
full_urls <- purrr::map(query_params, ~ modify_url(base_url, query = .))

# get a subset of the full urls to load for smaller sample
# full dataset appears to be 55.6 MB in size
full_urls_small <- full_urls[1:5]

# map over the full urls with geojson_sf
wbd_data <- purrr::map(full_urls_small, st_read)

# reduce to a dataframe where each row is an sf object
wbd_data_df <- wbd_data %>%
    purrr::reduce(bind_rows) %>%
    # texas has some weird lines going on inside the shape, but this does not
    # remove them like I thought it would
    st_make_valid()

# plot
leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addPolygons(data=wbd_data_df, weight=2, color="blue")
```

I think my initial issue was not fully understanding how to build the query. Using the [query tool](https://hydro.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/wbd/MapServer/1/query) found at the bottom of this [page](https://hydro.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/wbd/MapServer/1) was very helpful for debugging. This article [here](https://kdvdecisions-blog.netlify.app/2020/04/18/obtaining-spatial-data-from-esri-rest-apis-in-r/) pointed me in the right direction to make sure I was actually generating a correct query.

Comment: You need to include `purrr` or something that provides the `map` function to make this work, but I think that's making heavy work of sticking the id numbers into a URL string (maybe later work will be changing the template URL in more complex ways...idk) and I'd just use `paste0`. Also you can use `sf::st_read` on a URL and it will get the geoJSON - its possible what `geojson_sf` is doing anyway, but takes another potential dependency (failure point) out of your code.

Comment: Thanks for catching the missing `purrr`. I had it loaded in my environment so I didn't notice that. As for the heavy work, I will at some point be making more complicated calls, but I agree, if I can rework this it would be better. It seems overdone to map and apply a new id to each url. And you are correct on geojson_sf. I switched it to just be st_read and removed that dependency. Thank you!